# Excel Custom Ribbon Screentip

Tags: xml, excel

Is there any way I can remove the highlighted 'Tell me more' portion of a screentip as per the example below?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
        <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
<ribbon>
    <tabs>
        <tab id="customMANTIS" label="MANTIS" insertAfterMso="Developer">

            <group id="mantisSheetFunctions" label="Sheet Functions">
                <button id="customButton3" label="Insert Rows" screentip="Insert Rows" supertip="Insert rows at the current cursor position. Max 1000 rows at any one time." size="large" onAction="IRInsertNewRows" imageMso="CellsInsertDialog" />
                <button id="customButton4" label="Delete Rows" screentip="Delete Rows" supertip="Delete rows from the current cursor position down. Max 1000 rows at any one time." size="large" onAction="IRDeleteRows" imageMso="CellsDelete" />
                <button id="customButton5" label="PDF Sheet" screentip="Save Sheet as PDF" supertip="Saves the current sheet as a PDF document." size="large" onAction="IRPDFSheet" imageMso="FileSaveAsPdf" />
            </group>

            <group id="mantisWorkbookNavigation" label="Workbook Functions">
                <button id="customButton6" label="Insert Logo" screentip="Insert Logo" supertip="Apply your own company logo to the header portion of each sheet." size="large" onAction="IRInsertHeaderGraphic" imageMso="PicturePositionGallery" />
                <button id="customButton7" label="Save Workbook" screentip="Save Workbook As..." supertip="Creates and renames a copy of the Workbook." size="large" onAction="IRSaveAs" imageMso="FileSaveAs" />
                <button id="customButton8" label="PDF Workbook" screentip=" Save Workbook as PDF" supertip="Creates a PDF file of the entire Workbook." size="large" onAction="IRLockWorkbook" imageMso="FileSaveAsPdfOrXps" />
            </group>            

            <group id="mantisNavigation" label="Navigation">
                <button id="customButton1" label="Previous Sheet" screentip="Previous Sheet" supertip="Navigates back one sheet at a time." size="large" onAction="IRPrevPg" imageMso="PreviousResource" />
                <button id="customButton2" label="Next Sheet" screentip="Next Sheet" supertip="Navigates forward one sheet at a time." size="large" onAction="IRNextPg" imageMso="NextResource" />
            </group>

            <group id="mantisHelp" label="Help">
                <button id="customButton9" label="View Versions" screentip="View Versions Sheet" supertip="Displays the Version Control sheet. Contains a detailed record of each version change." size="large" onAction="IRVersions" imageMso="Info" />
                <button id="customButton10" label="Help" screentip="Instructions File" supertip="Allows for the online reading or downloading of the instructions file for the calculator. An active internet connection is required." size="large" onAction="IRInstructionFile" imageMso="Help" />
            </group>

        </tab>
    </tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Comment: As the exelguru says [here](http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2006/12/14/modifying-the-ribbon-part-11/) in comments: *We can't touch the workbook name, the gear, or even remove the F1 for help line. Quite irritating, that.* (followed by a sad face emoticon). Also as this MS forum [shows](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8ce9637b-542a-489e-b0df-db1185b8aab6/ribbon-customisation-how-do-i-changeremove-the-tell-me-more-link-to-word-help?forum=worddev): *No, there's absolutely nothing anyone can do about this - it's hard-coded into the Ribbon behavior.*

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I did find reference to this fact via other means later yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably solved, but for others: if you use

```
getScreentip = "ScreentipMacroName"
```

you should only see the text output from the macro [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFnZj.png)